# Arch install Compiz

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, compiz

I'm using arch, and want to install Xfce with Compiz. I saw on tutorials what packages to install , but when I try to install them with `pacman -S compiz-...`, I only get things like: `error: target not found: ccsm`. How do I get to the packages?

Comment: I added a script to my answer that I hope helps

Answer (score 1):

[Compiz packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz) have been moved to the [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR) (Arch User Repository). This repository is unsupported so is not accessible by pacman.

You can download the packages you require and use `makepkg` to install them. See the Arch Wiki [AUR page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR) for the details on using this repository.

Comment: Is there a way to 'add' the Repository like in Ubuntu? I don't understand any of this.

Comment: @MadTux You should take the time to understand it; PKGBUILDS in AUR could contain malicious code and you should always review them before running `makepkg`. The wiki explains it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Yaourt for installing the package from AUR. For xfce desktop 
use:

```
yaourt -S ccsm compiz-core compiz-fusion-plugins-extra libcompizconfig compiz-manager
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: @MadTux [I wrote you a script that installs the *Compiz* packages](http://goo.gl/hzNv4q). Successfully tested on a fresh install!

I also forgot to mention that *XFCE* [comes with its own compositor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce4#Enabling_the_Compositor) (not as many features as *Compiz* though)

---

Install an [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_Helpers) such as `packer`

I have `compiz` successfully working on a couple up-to-date ArchLinux machines. You need these packages:

```
ccsm 0.8.4-4
compiz-bcop 0.8.8-2
compiz-core 0.8.8-5
compiz-decorator-gtk 0.8.8-5
compiz-fusion-plugins-extra 0.8.8-2
compiz-fusion-plugins-main 0.8.8-2
compizconfig-backend-gconf 0.8.8-2
compizconfig-python 0.8.4-4
emerald 0.8.8-2
emerald-themes 0.6.0-4
fusion-icon-fixed 1:0.1-1
libcompizconfig 0.8.8-2
```

As you can see I'm using the "old" *0.8.X* branch (0.9 breaks everything).
Many of the compiz packages in [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&K=compiz) will not build.

Therefore you may need to use the [Arch Rollback Machine (ARM)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_Packages#Arch_Rollback_Machine) for the ones that fail to compile.

```
[community]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
Server = http://arm.konnichi.com/2013/04/01/community/os/$arch
```

*NOTE: To use the A.R.M. you do **not** use `[custom]` it must be the original name of the repo so `pacman` can find the `.db` database file. Remember to revert the config file back to normal afterwards.*

Comment: Why would you point [community] at ARM? That's what [custom] is for...

Comment: To prevent dependency issues (after-all packages in [community] are newer than [community-2013-05-01]). Immediately after installing the needed packages, revert `pacman.conf`

Comment: Doing this yourself seems like an odd choice; recommending it to someone who still hasn't grasped the distinction between supported and unsupported repos seems rather perverse.

Comment: @jasonwryan You're right, I don't expect the OP to 'get it' but wanted to provide the relevant information for others instead of "sorry. compiz is deprecated. no compiz for you". At least my advice is better than download each compiz-related package's `PKGBUILD` **manually** like you suggested and hope it works.

Comment: The problem is that your "relevant information for others" is 1) wrong, and 2) only likely to lead to further confusion. If you want to recommend the ARM, do it [properly](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_Packages#Arch_Rollback_Machine)...